# Attempt to rewrite a page not found before displaying 404 error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, routes, url-rewriting

The rails codebase that I'm working on supports two web applications, and we use apache to rewrite the url intelligently when a user comes to our domain, so for example if you approach our site from

app_name.domain_name.com

it is rewritten to

app_name.domain_name.com/app_name

and our nested routes are called.  This is a recent change to our app however, and (obviously) some bookmarks aren't forwarding properly.  What I'd like to do is modify our routes (or maybe add a small piece of middleware) which attempts tot rewrite to the correct url rather than displaying a 404 message.

That is to say, if a customer tries to view

app_name.domain_name.com/controller/action

our nested routes miss the call, and instead of 404ing, the app rewrites the request to:

app_name.domain_name.com/app_name/controller/action

Can I do this with either a clever route, or with some middleware?  If not, can this be done with apache rewrites?

Thanks

Comment: Post the excerpt for your apache rewrite please.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^web_app.benchmark.company.net$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1web_app [L,R=permanent]`  Sorry, I can't get the newlines to be respected, but I hope it is obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^web_app.benchmark.company.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) /web_app/$1 [L,R=permanent]
```

(Note that I have not tested this)

I recommend you read the [Apache rewrite guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/).